# Is it possible to add swap space on kubernetes nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to add swap space on kubernetes node to prevent it from out of memory issue. Is it possible to add swap space on node (previously known as minion)? If possible what procedure should I follow and how it effects pods acceptance test?

Comment: Kubelet doesn't set the the swap space size, so I think if you want to adjust the swap space size of a k8s node, you will have to do it in the same way as you do on a non-k8s machine.

Answer (score 22):

Kubernetes doesn't support container memory swap. Even if you add swap space, kubelet will create the container with --memory-swappiness=0 (when using Docker). There have been discussions about adding support, but the proposal was not approved. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7294

Comment: Has it changed since then?

Comment: @FtheBuilder - seems like it did: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/08/09/run-nodes-with-swap-alpha/

Comment: update 
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/08/24/swap-linux-beta/

Answer (score 5):

**Technically** you can do it.
There is a broad discussion weather to give K8S users the privilege to decide enabling swap or not.

I'll first refer directly to your question and then continue with the discussion.

If you run K8S on [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) and you've added swap to your nodes - **follow the steps below**:

1 ) Reset the current cluster setup and then add the `fail-swap-on=false` flag to the kubelet configuration:

```
kubeadm reset 
echo 'Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false"' >> /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

(*) If you're running on Ubuntu replace the path for the Kubelet config from `etc/systemd/syste,/kubelet` to `/etc/default/kubelet`.

2 ) Reload the service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

3 ) Initialize the cluster settings again and ignore the swap error:

```
kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors Swap
```

OR:

If you prefer working with `kubeadm-config.yaml`:

1 ) Add the `failSwapOn` flag:

```
---
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
failSwapOn: false # <---- Here
```

2 ) And run:

```
kubeadm init --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap
```

---

**Returning back to discussion weather to allow swapping or not.**

From the one hand, K8S is very clear about this - Kubelet is not designed to support swap - you can see it mentioned in the Kubeadm link I shared above:

> Swap disabled. You MUST disable swap in order for the kubelet to work
> properly

From the other hand, you can see users reporting that there are cases where there deployments require swap enabled.

**I would suggest that you first try without enabling swap**. 
(Not because swap is a function that the kernel can't manage, but merely because it is not recommended by Kube - probably related to the design of Kubelet).

**Make sure that you are familiar with the features that K8S provides to prioritize memory of pods**:

1 ) The [3 qos classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/#qos-classes) - Make sure that your high priority workloads are running with the `Guaranteed` (or at least `Burstable`) class.

2 ) [Pod Priority and Preemption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/).

I would recommend also reading [Evicting end-user Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#evicting-end-user-pods):

> If the kubelet is unable to reclaim sufficient resource on the node,
> kubelet begins evicting Pods.
>
> The kubelet ranks Pods for eviction first by whether or not their
> usage of the starved resource exceeds requests, then by Priority, and
> then by the consumption of the starved compute resource relative to
> the Pods' scheduling requests.
>
> As a result, kubelet ranks and evicts Pods in the following order:
>
> - BestEffort or Burstable Pods whose usage of a starved resource exceeds its request. Such pods are ranked by Priority, and then usage
>   above request.
> - Guaranteed pods and Burstable pods whose usage is beneath requests are evicted last. Guaranteed Pods are guaranteed only when requests
>   and limits are specified for all the containers and they are equal.
>   Such pods are guaranteed to never be evicted because of another Pod's
>   resource consumption. If a system daemon (such as kubelet, docker, and
>   journald) is consuming more resources than were reserved via
>   system-reserved or kube-reserved allocations, and the node only has
>   Guaranteed or Burstable Pods using less than requests remaining, then
>   the node must choose to evict such a Pod in order to preserve node
>   stability and to limit the impact of the unexpected consumption to
>   other Pods. In this case, it will choose to evict pods of Lowest
>   Priority first.

Good luck (:

---

A few relevant discussions:

[Kubelet/Kubernetes should work with Swap Enabled](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53533)

[[ERROR Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/610)

[Kubelet needs to allow configuration of container memory-swap](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7294)

Answer (score 3):

In 2021 Kubernetes 1.22 introduced swap as an alpha feature.

In 2023 Kubernetes 1.28 introduced swap as an beta feature.

More at:

- https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/08/09/run-nodes-with-swap-alpha/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#swap-memory
- https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/08/24/swap-linux-beta/

Answer (score -1):

It is generally recommended to disable swap on Kubernetes nodes for several reasons:

Performance: Kubernetes workloads typically run in containers, which are isolated and have their own resource limits. If a container exceeds its resource limit and tries to use swap, the performance of the node and other containers running on the same node may be severely impacted.

Stability: Kubernetes relies on the Linux kernel's out-of-memory (OOM) killer to terminate processes that exceed their memory limits. If swap is enabled, the OOM killer may not work as expected, leading to unpredictable behavior and potential instability.

Security: Swap may contain sensitive data that should not be exposed to other containers or users on the same node. Disabling swap helps to minimize the risk of data leakage and unauthorized access.

Predictability: Kubernetes relies on the Linux kernel's memory management to enforce resource limits and ensure predictable behavior. Swap can introduce additional complexity and unpredictability into the memory management process.

Overall, disabling swap on Kubernetes nodes is a best practice that helps to ensure performance, stability, security, and predictability of Kubernetes workloads.